# Should I tag language A if I ask about "How to I do x in language B like in language A"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was going to ask a question about how I can do X in language B like in language A, where I cannot find similar features in language B.

I don't know whether I should also tag language A because I am asking language B and people may find my language B questions when searching using language A tag

Comment: Wouldn't be harmful if you add it. Please ensure that your post doesn't look like a *code conversion request*

Answer (score 17):

It's usually not a good idea. I often remove tag A from questions like that, because the question is *not about* A.

1. It creates noise for those who follow the A tag (and don't know B).
2. Whenever I see such questions it would have been better to clearly explain the feature in a language-agnostic way.

Keep in mind that literal translations are usually a bad idea. The feature might be the best solution in language A, but terribly inefficient in language B.

Comment: Another issue with tagging these questions with A is that sometimes it can cause the page title to be "A - <question title>" on a question that's really about B, which can be confusing when seeing it as a result on Google. This happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50549611/4284627) before I edited it.